# Calculating amount of elements in an array with a template function

Tags: c++, arrays, templates

I was looking for a way to make a template function that calculated the amount of elements in an array, without passing in the entire array, but just a pointer to it. And so I came up with this:

```
template <typename T>
long int calculateElements(T* someArray) {
    return (sizeof(T) / sizeof(&someArray));
};
```

Now, my sense tells me that this shouldn't work, but it does!

Say I have an array with 10 integers. `T` would be an `int`, so `sizeof(T)` would be `4`, `someArray` would be a pointer to an int array, so `sizeof(&someArray)` would be 10 times the size of an integer (`10*sizeof(T)`), which would be `40`. The function should return 0, but it doesn't.

Can anyone explain to me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Your sense was right. It shouldn't work and furthermore it doesn't work.

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3a4b7168d56c18a7 Code does not behave as described

Comment: passing pointer to array would involve array decay issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may work with reference to array:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
constexpr std::size_t calculateElements(const T (&)[N])
{
    return N;
}
```

[Live example](http://ideone.com/PFScGr).

Currently you return `sizeof(T) / sizeof(T**)` which is size of the element divided by the size of a pointer (4 on 32 bits and 8 on 64 bits).

Comment: Great ! But OP must be aware that T (&)[N] can only work with fixed size arrays, and not with dynamic arrays (pointers) nor array parameters.

Comment: @Christophe This *is* an array parameter. I think you mean arrays of indeterminate size, i.e. `T[]` with nothing between the brackets. An parameter of type array of indeterminate size *is* a pointer, due to the function parameter decay rule.

Comment: @Potatoswatter that's exactly what I wanted to point out !! And the solution is great, because unlike the error prone sizeof() approach, this one will produce a compile error when used with a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use C++11 and read about `std::array`. It works like ordinary C++ table, but it has some of container interface methods. Probably you will be interest `std::array::size()`.

Comment: +1 because tricks with sizeof() to calculate number of elements of an array, do only work for arrays of fixed size (known at compile time), and not with arrays passed as parameter.